# How is relevance of results on froogle determined?

Tags: seo

I have a client who sells shoes, and is included on froogle.  However, results are quite skewed for other stuff when I do a search for their name on froogle:
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=shop&q=shermanbrothers&oq=shermanbrothers&gs_l=products-cc.3...4555.6166.0.6455.15.8.0.7.0.0.159.739.5j3.8.0...0.0...1ac.fFUuy61zkHg#hl=en&tbm=shop&sclient=psy-ab&q=shermanbrothers&oq=shermanbrothers&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.654235.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.98nQoMkQujk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=aabf81530f08f356&biw=1304&bih=680

So what factors affect relevance on froogle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Google](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160081) there are a number of factors, they key being to make sure you supply as much data as possible in your feed. However, any optimization of a Google product feed may be a moot point, since Google announced that they are changing the product search to [Google Shopping](http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2012/05/building-better-shopping-experience.html), which will no longer be a free service.

Also Froogle is [now called](http://searchengineland.com/goodbye-froogle-hello-google-product-search-11001) Google Product search, so you shouldn't refer to that name.

Comment: Ah, good call. I guess that makes the answer: optimize by paying... :p